# Skip columns pandas/multiple empty lists separated by comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to write some dataframe to a csv file. However, the columns F to N should me empty. This is the dataframe I'm using:

```
data = [['car'], ['bus'], ['laptop'], ['tv', 'chair'], ['music', 'pop'], ['shoe']]
dataFrame = pandas.DataFrame(data).transpose()
```

The first five lists are going in the columns A to E, respectively . For example, `'laptop'` is going under column C. However, with the current code `'shoe'` goes under column F. Is there a way to tell this dataFrame that it should skip columns F to N and write `'shoe'` under column O? In other words, there should be empty columns between the columns E and O.

If this isn't possible. I assumed that it's at least possible to write `[], [], []` many times. Is there a way to make these empty lists separated by commas with a `for` loop or something?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you want empty columns before 'shoe', or you just want the names of the columns to be A, B, C, D, E, O?

Comment: I just need to put this data in the columns A, B, C, D, E and O

Comment: your columns don't have names at this point so you could just name them...

Comment: It's not about naming the columns. With column O I mean column O in csv

Comment: column O in a csv file is just a label excel provides to a csv file. You are saying that you would like columns to be filled.

Comment: If you opened the output csv file in notepad you would not see column labels A-O

Comment: I think I might have confused some of you. Here is an update on my answer: In other words, there should be empty columns between columns E and O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should work with a `dictionary` instead of a list, that way you can explicitly state which columns each list should be part of. Then reindex so they appear in the proper position.

```
import pandas as pd
import string

data = {'A': ['car'], 'B': ['bus'], 'C': ['laptop'], 
        'D': ['tv', 'chair'], 'E': ['music', 'pop'], 'O':['shoe']}
df = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
        .reindex(list(string.ascii_uppercase))
        .truncate(after='O', axis=0).T)
```

#### Output:

```
      A     B       C      D      E    F    G    H    I    J    K    L    M    N     O
0   car   bus  laptop     tv  music  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  shoe
1  None  None    None  chair    pop  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  None
```

Now if you do `df.to_csv('file_name.csv', index=False, header=False)` the columns will be as you want in your .csv.

#### CSV Output:

```
car,bus,laptop,tv,music,,,,,,,,,,shoe
,,,chair,pop,,,,,,,,,,
```

---

If you ever need even more columns, then the first 702 excel columns are:

```
from itertools import product
l = list(string.ascii_uppercase)+[x+y for x,y in product(string.ascii_uppercase, string.ascii_uppercase)]
```

Comment: How do I handle this if the columns names are different? This means not A to O

Comment: Well what do you want the Column names to be? You can specify their names in the dictionary (as I have) and then pass a list to reindex to specify the order you want them to appear.

Comment: If I change the column names to random names the code does not do the job.

Comment: @jxpython Well yes, obviously. You can't just expect the reindex to magically know exactly how you want things to be ordered. The key to my solution is that you provide the column names in the dictionary, and then provide the order you want them to appear in the `.reindex(some_list)` step. If you change the names to something random in the dictionary, you also need to provide a new list that contains those random names, so it knows how to order them.  Perhaps look at [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

Answer (score 1):

This inserts 9 empty lists before `shoe`, putting shoe in the `O` column

```
for i in range(9):
    data.insert(-1, [])
dataFrame = pandas.DataFrame(data).transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
In [1]: ll = [[] for x in range(5)]

In [2]: ll
Out[2]: [[], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas [`insert()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html#) over a range of values:

```
import string
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase

[dataFrame.insert(i, f"{alphabet[i]}", '') for i in range(5,14)]

dataFrame
      0     1       2      3      4 F G H I J K L M N     5
0   car   bus  laptop     tv  music                    shoe
1  None  None    None  chair    pop                    None
```